# How to use external cpp projects in a cpp project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, cppunit

i m trying to make  small test driven example by using cppunit. So i have 2 project which are test and normal library project. Whatever i  do, i cannot be successfull.  i got alltime LNK Error. Any help will be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test program needs to have a dependency on the library, so that it links against it.

In addition to this, you need to add the cppunit libraries as additional libraries, in the "properties -> linker -> input" section of the test program.

Comment: It's not your project, but the cppunit libraries that you need to add to the "input" section.